# C - Can't figure out this error : "C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value"

Tags: c

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to try and learn C language.

I'm using the famous [K&R book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) and after literally copying and pasting the following piece of code from the book to Visual Studio 2013 i got the error :

> 1 error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
>   2 IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1 /* inside a word */
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */
/* count lines, words, and characters in input */
main()
{
    int c, nl, nw, nc, state;
    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl;
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) 
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
}
```

it seems the error comes from the statement :

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
```

But i really can't figure what's wrong, not mentioning the fact that the code is straight from the book.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps your clipboard is broken

Comment: :3. I guess i need a break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c = '\t')
//                             ^ Oops.
```

I suggest you take a break. Even without knowing that the assignment would try to write to the result of `||` because it has lower precedence, the discrepancy is screaming.

Comment: Godamnit i've been reading the code for the last hour :/ ! I feel silly now. Thanks for your help anyway !

Comment: @xashcorex don't forget to accept one of our answers if the question is solved :)

Comment: I will, 4 more minutes to go :)

Answer (score 3):

Change `c = '\t'` to `c == '\t'` in `if`'s condition. Otherwise the conditional expression will be parsed as

```
 if ( ((c == ' ' || c == '\n') || c) = '\t')
```

`((c == ' ' || c == '\n') || c)` is a rvalue (Boolean value; a constant) and it is not assignable (its like `1 = 2`).

Comment: Ah, Yoda conditions ;)

Comment: @ouah; Yeah its ugly but sometimes work as a savior. BTW, removed that :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the existing

```
 c = '\t'
```

to

```
 c == '\t'
```

Otherwise, because of the higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of `||` than `=`, your code will behave like

```
 if ( (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c ) = '\t')
```

now, as we know, the result of a logical OR operation [`int` 1 or `int` 0] is not a modifiable lvaue, you'll see the error.

Just for reference, from chapter 6.5.14, paragraph 3, `C99` standard,

> The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

So, a `1 = '\t'` or `0 = '\t'` is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 1):

No one explained the reason why you get that error.

Focus on this part of the expression - `c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c`. Suppose it evaluated to some value say `1` (just a random example). Then you cannot store `'\t'` in `1` like this `1 = '\t'`.

This will evaluate to an expression which is an [rvalue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx) and you cannot store `'\t'` in it.

However this is perfectly legal, even though your code might not work as you expected:

```
if (c = '\t' || c == ' ' || c == '\n')
  note^
```

Comment: I did, briefly I admit.